# jquery check user browser type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `$.browser` to try and check what type of browser users have accessing my site. The problem I have however is that both **Safari** and **Chrome** are webkit browsers and I therefore do not know how to distinguish between the too.

Is there a way to distinguish between safari and chrome so that I can have my site do something different?

Comment: check this question, it may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 1.6 Browser detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674246/jquery-1-6-browser-detection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function browserTester(browserString) {
    return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(browserString) > -1;
}

if(browserTester('chrome')) {
    // do stuff for chrome
} else if(browserTester('safari')) {
    //do stuff for safari
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/gm3Na/

Comment: ah great this will probably do the trick. Can you confirm if I can pass in 'msie', 'opera' and 'mozilla' into these if else statements too?

Comment: @Cliftwalker: yes. you can. In lowercase!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `navigator.userAgent` to find this out.

**Some sample outputs**:
Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1
```

Firefox:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
```

Safari:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7) AppleWebKit/534.48.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.48.3
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bQrgB/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a similar topic:
[Distinguish Chrome from Safari using jQuery.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303858/distinguish-chrome-from-safari-using-jquery-browser)

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

// Is this a version of Chrome?
if($.browser.chrome){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('chrome/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
  // If it is chrome then jQuery thinks it's safari so we have to tell it it isn't
  $.browser.safari = false;
}

// Is this a version of Safari?
if($.browser.safari){
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(userAgent.indexOf('safari/') +7);
  userAgent = userAgent.substring(0,userAgent.indexOf('.'));
  $.browser.version = userAgent;
}
```